# Applying low pass/median filter over DEM in GeoTIFF format using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, focal-statistics, spatial-filter

I want to apply a median/low pass filter (over a few hundred kilometers) over my DEM to reduce the noise. I tried ArcGIS focal statistics tool but no luck. I got a blank GeoTIFF file.

How can I do it and get reasonable results in GeoTIFF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS 10.x has a tool in the spatial analyst toolset called Majority Filter which will replace cells in a raster based on the values of their neighbors.  [Here is a link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/majority-filter.htm) to the tool which is available at all license levels.
If you do not have access to the spatial analyst tool in ArcGIS then you have the option of doing this analysis using open source software like QGIS.  [Here is a link](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/grid_filter.html) to the grid filter tools in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not stuck with ArcGIs you can apply the [Median filter](https://jblindsay.github.io/wbt_book/available_tools/image_processing_tools_filters.html#MedianFilter) from the [WhiteboxTools](https://jblindsay.github.io/ghrg/WhiteboxTools/index.html). It works like a charm and you can also chose from a series of other filters if you want to compare results. You can use it via Python or a simple command line. It's free and open source enjoy!

Comment: Why voted down?